# Get Model Attribute from HttpServletrequest in OncePerRequestFilter Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

I am using [flashAttributes](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/) to send data from one controller to other controller using `POST/Redirect/GET` strategy. But I need to access the model attribute in my filter class. My filter class looks like this.

```
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
 @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
 }
 }
```

Is there any way to get modelAttribute from `HttpServeletRequest`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found answer after lot of struggle. I can able to get the flashAttributes using this code in filters.

```
FlashMap flashMap =new SessionFlashMapManager().retrieveAndUpdate(request,null);
if (flashMap != null) {
    value = (String)flashMap.get("key");

}
```